# Maximum subset sum with two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, subset-sum

I am not even sure if this can be done in polynomial time.

Problem:

> Given two arrays of real numbers,
>
> ```
> A = (a[1], a[2], ..., a[n]), 
> B = (b[1], b[2], ..., b[n]),  (b[j] > 0, j = 1, 2, ..., n)
> ```
>
> and a number `k`, find a subset `A'` of `A (A' = (a[i(1)],
>   a[i(2)], ..., a[i(k)]))`, which contains exactly `k` elements, such that, `(sum a[i(j)])/(sum b[i(j)])` is maximized, where
> `j = 1, 2, ..., k`.

For example, if `k == 3`, and `{a[1], a[5], a[7]}` is the result, then

```
(a[1] + a[5] + a[7])/(b[1] + b[5] + b[7])
```

should be larger than any other combination. Any clue?

Comment: I guess this is NP-Hard by 99.99% chance, but can I ask you where do you see this problem? In all it's really nice question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I reduced a real load balancing problem to this abstract version. I have spent more than two days on this problem. Now, I also have a feeling that it is NP-hard.

Comment: There are `n` choose `k` possible ratios, so that sets the upper bound on complexity. I was considering a way to pick the largest ratio `a[i]/b[i]` to start, then pick the index that makes the `k=2` case as large as possible. This way you have to compare `n-1` ratios on that step. Then continue by picking the third index. Proving that this will always give the best ratio once you've picked `k` indices may be hard (or it may not be true!), but trying to prove may offer some insight.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to prove the correctness of your algorithm yesterday, but end up in a counter example. check this A = [10, 2, 1, 0.2], B = [7, 3, 2, 1.34], and k = 3.

Comment: Can a[i] and b[i] be zero or negative?

Comment: @Geni - I suspected a counterexample like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the entries of `B` are positive (it sounds as though this special case might be useful to you), there is an `O(n^2 log n)` algorithm.

Let's first solve the problem of deciding, for a particular `t`, whether there exists a solution such that

```
(sum a[i(j)])/(sum b[i(j)]) >= t.
```

Clearing the denominator, this condition is equivalent to

```
sum (a[i(j)] - t*b[i(j)]) >= 0.
```

All we have to do is choose the `k` largest values of `a[i(j)] - t*b[i(j)]`.

Now, in order to solve the problem when `t` is unknown, we use a kinetic algorithm. Think of `t` as being a time variable; we are interested in the evolution of a one-dimensional physical system with `n` particles having initial positions `A` and velocities `-B`. Each particle crosses each other particle at most one time, so the number of events is `O(n^2)`. In between crossings, the optimum of `sum (a[i(j)] - t*b[i(j)])` changes linearly, because the same subset of `k` is optimal.

Comment: I suspect that there's an `O(n^2)` algorithm that uses arrangements of lines and the computational-geometric machinery that has been developed to handle them.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. I never saw something like this. I'm curious if this method can be applied to a larger class of problems and what this type of solution is called...or did you pull this out of thin air?

Comment: @JohnPS Kinetic algorithms are a design technique favored by computational geometers. They're applicable when you have a continuous parameter (interpreted as time) and a "physical system" that changes nicely except at finitely many times.

Answer (score 2):

If B can contain negative numbers, then this is NP-Hard.

Because of the NP-Hardness of this problem:

> Given k and array B, is there a subset of size k of B which sums to zero.

The A becomes immaterial in that case.

Of course, from your comment it seems like B must contain positive numbers.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I forgot to mention that B contains only positive numbers.