# Specific subset of index set with minimum sum in an array

Tags: algorithm

You have 2 arrays a and b, each contains n numbers. You have a number k.

[n] = the index set 1...n

We want to find the subset S of [n] such that the sum of elements indexed by S in a is at least k, and the sum of elements indexed by S in b is as small is possible.

I'm unable to find even a polynomial time algorithm for this. I'd be grateful for any ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Is this homework? What approaches have you come up with so far? The subset S is not necessarily contiguous elements, right?

Comment: The following similar questions may give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099334/maximum-subset-sum-with-two-arrays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443712/algorithm-to-find-subset-within-two-sets-of-integers-whose-sums-match/443950#443950

Comment: This is not homework. I am reading up a problem on allocating resources to players which reduces to this in a special case. I see now that this is NP-complete. Knapsack can be solved in polynomial time up to any accuracy, and we can also reduce this to knapsack by binary searching on target value. So, I guess this can also be solved in polynomial time to any accuracy, I'll have to verify this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general solution to this problem is NP-complete, because it subsumes the knapsack problem.  However, as with the knapsack problem, you may be able to address it constructively (in "pseudopolynomial time") using dynamic programming.

---

To see this:  given a knapsack problem with knapsack size `T` and object sizes `c[i]`, compose a problem as described in your question such that `a[i]==b[i]==c[i]` and `k == sum(c[i]) - T`.

Then, the solution to the knapsack problem is the set of indices *not* in `S`:

```
sum(c[i] *not* indexed by S) == sum(c[i]) - sum(a[i] indexed by S)

T == sum(c[i]) - k
```

Note that `S` satisfies knapsack constraint `sum(c[i] *not* indexed by S) <= T` if and only if the problem constraint `sum(a[i] indexed by S) >= k` holds.

```
sum(c[i] *not* indexed by S) == sum(c[i]) - sum(b[i] indexed by S)
```

Since a solution to the posed problem minimizes `sum(b[i] indexed by S)` over valid S, `sum(c[i] *not* indexed by S)` is maximized over valid S, and is an optimal solution of the knapsack problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in at least polynomial, right?
Easy to have exponential iterating all masks for the set and checking both conditions (sum >= k and compare what we had before in sum of b and now)